# regex to extract number in a pattern like this (numbers)(a-dash-meaning-end-of-number)(not needed text)

Tags: regex

i need a regex for php that returns the number from strings where starts with numbers and a dash "-" means the number ends. like this:

11111-not_needed_rest_of_string (must return 11111)

123-ASdaSDaSDaSDASDASD (must return 123)

1-12312312312 (must return 1)

102---9.... (must return 102)

a1-hehehe (must not match since "a1" is not a number)

Thank you guys

p.s. i want INTEGERS so 1,2-asdasd must not match

Comment: What if you don't have a dash? `23a`, or `123`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
/^(\d+)-/
```

(oh god 30 character limit)

Comment: @easy_weezy: The slashes are only needed in certain regex flavors and must be omitted in others. You didn't specify which one you're using. Also the handling of backslashes may be different.

Comment: that was the fastest response ever! thank you CanSpice! it works of course ;)